# How do I remove the $ sign and the comma from the annualsalary column like $50,000 to 50000?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column named annualsalary with varchar2 data type.  In this column, I have values like $25,000, $67,000, etc. I want to get rid of both $ sign and the comma. I am able to do only one replace function and get rid of the dollarsign. But how do I get rid of the comma in the same query?

I tried doing it with the following query but I'm unable to get rid of comma.

```
SELECT REPLACE(ANNUALINCOME,'$','') AS column_variable FROM table_name;
```

It got rid of the $ sign and showed me the output as 50,000. But now I want to remove comma as well to make it 50000.

Comment: Why did you specify muliple databases?  Please specify only the one that this question is about.

Comment: varchar2 is oracle. Removed MySQL & SQL Server tag

Answer (score 0):

Nest `replace`s

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(ANNUALINCOME,'$',''), ',', '') AS column_variable 
FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TO_NUMBER`:

```sql
SELECT TO_NUMBER(value, '$999G999G999D99') AS amount
FROM   table_name;
```

*Note: this has advantages over `REPLACE` in that it only requires a single function call and, more importantly, it converts the value from a string to a number so that if you sort the data then it will be sorted numerically and not alpha-numerically.*

*Note 2: You should **store** `ANNUALINCOME` as a `NUMBER` data type and not as a formatted string and can apply the appropriate formatting using `TO_CHAR` when you want to **display** the value rather than doing it reversed.*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT '$25,000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '$67,000' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | AMOUNT |
> | --- |
> | 25000 |
> | 67000 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c185c1686886a869833fe51237f4fb1d)*